# Is it possible to combine two Linux conditions?

Tags: csh

In Linux you can perform simple command line conditions such as.

```
echo 'The short brown fox' | grep -q 'fox' && echo 'Found' || echo 'Not Found'

>> Found
```

Or

```
test -e test.txt && echo 'File Exists' || echo 'File Not Found'
>> File exists
```

Is it possible to combine the two conditions into one? So if the fox is found, we look to see if the file is present then execute the condition accordingly.

I have tried the following and they don't appear to work:

```
echo 'The short brown fox' | grep -q 'fox' && (test -e test.txt && echo 'File Exists' || echo 'File Not Found') || echo 'Fox Not Found'

echo 'The short brown fox' | grep -q 'fox' && `test -e test.txt && echo 'File Exists' || echo 'File Not Found'` || echo 'Fox Not Found'
```

I need the command to take place on a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{ ...; }` to group multiple commands in shell like this:

```
echo 'The short brown fox' | grep -q 'fox' &&
{ [[ -e test.txt ]] && echo "file exists" || echo 'File Not Found'; } || echo 'Not Found'
```

All of the command inside curly braces i.e. `{ ...; }` will be executed when `grep` is successful and `||` outside `{ ...; }` is evaluated for `grep` failure.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is `csh` one liner doing same:

```
echo 'The short brown ox' | grep -q 'fox' && ( [ -e "test.txt" ] && echo "file exists" || echo 'File Not Found' ; ) || echo 'Not Found'
```

Comment: This just appears to error: {: Command not found.
File Not Found
}: Command not found.
Not Found

Comment: What shell are you using? This worked fine for me in `bash`

Comment: I am using -csh

Answer (score 2):

Don't combine `||` and `&&` like this; use an explicit `if` statement.

```
if echo 'The short brown fox' | grep -q 'fox'; then
    if test -e test.txt; then
        echo "File found"
    else
        echo "File not found"
    fi
else
    echo "Not found"
fi
```

`a && b || c` is not equivalent if `a` succeeds and `b` fails (although you could use `a && { b || c; }`, but the `if` statement is more readable).

Comment: This cannot be run on a single line though.

Comment: Sure it can; `if ...; then if ...; then echo; else; echo; fi; else echo; fi`. But do you want a short command, or a *correct* command? Pretty much anywhere you see newline in shell, you can replace it with a semi-colon.

Comment: Just noticed noticed the change to `csh` in the tag. Not sure if this answer still applies, but there are a lot of reasons to switch from `csh` to `bash` (or at least something related to POSIX).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! You can use the and and or operators like this:

```
echo "The short brown fox" | grep fox && echo found || echo not found
```

If you want to suppress the output of `grep` as well so that you only see "found" or "not found", you can do:

```
echo "The short brown fox" | grep fox >/dev/null && echo found || echo not found
```

The `&&` operator and `||` operators are short circuiting, so if `echo "The short brown fox" | grep fox >/dev/null` return a truthy exit code (0), then the `echo found` will execute, and since that also returns an exit code of 0, the `echo not found` will never execute.

Similarly, if `echo "The short brown fox" | grep fox >/dev/null` returns a falsey exit code (>0), then the `echo found` will not execute at all, and the `echo not found` will execute.